# Is there a more "Combine" way to do this?

Tags: swift

I've got one .map command in an API that I am creating that I'm pretty sure can be done in a better way...

The code is:

```
.map {
    var myTags = [Tag]()
    for name in $0 {
        myTags.append(Tag(name: name))
    }
    return myTags
}
```

Can I do this without having to create a temporary variable??

Thanks!

Comment: Why is there a for name in $0? Is the map object an array?

Comment: It is inside of a function with the signature of:

func tags() -> AnyPublisher<[Tag], Error> {

So, yes, it is an array of Tag objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `Combine`, this is simple Swift code.
You can replace that with a single `map` call though.

```
.map { names in
    return names.map { Tag(name: $0) }
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
.map { $0.map(Tag.init) }
```

Comment: Ugh, DUH!  Thank you, an extra set of eyes always helps!

Comment: Actually can be even shorter: `.map { $0.map { Tag(name: $0 }}`

Comment: There is already a function so you don't need to create a new closure: `.map { $0.map(Tag.init) }` or `.map { $0.map( Tag.init(name:) ) }`